# World Space Canvas rendered "on top of everything" Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface

I am developing a VR application in Unity, and I need to add subtitles. I have added a `World Space Canvas` to the `MainCamera`, and I want it to be rendered on top of every other `GameObject` in the scene, to allow the player to see the subtitles in every possible situation.

In other words, I would like to use this `Canvas` as if it was `Screen Space - Overlay`. I cannot however use it like this, as Unity in VR does not support it.

I already attached the `Canvas` to the `MainCamera`, but if there are some `GameObjects` that are nearer to the `MainCamera` than the `Canvas` it will be hidden. I want to avoid this situation.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Make the world space UI a child of your camera and place it at a defined (z) distance. Enable/Disable it on demand.

Make sure your camera near clipping plane is smaller than the UI's distance to the camera otherwise it won't get rendered.

Edit: If putting the world space canvas right at the near clipping plane isn't sufficient, maybe you can use a second camera for UI stuff if having a second camera is an option for you. As far as I know this is also possible for VR applications. Make sure the UI is drawn on top by setting a higher depth value on the camera.

Comment: I already did this, but if the canvas goes "inside" a game object it will not be displayed.

Comment: Is using a second camera an option for you?

Comment: Mmm...I am not sure if using a second camera could be a suitable solution for VR

Comment: Have you tried? Lastly I can only suggest to write a custom shader which when applied renders your UI objects on top of everything else. From what I have seen so far the 2nd camera approach should be more straightforward but maybe you're a shader expert:)